# why does this simple code throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class AClasse {
 String a;
 public AClasse(String a){
    this.a = a;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args){
    AClasse[] clases = new AClasse[10];
    clases[0].a = "?"; // the exception is in this line 
 }
}
```

whats the reason and whats the right equivalent statement.

Comment: What do you think is under `clases[0]` when you call `clases[0].a`?

Comment: Initializing an array doesn't initialize the elements inside the array.

Comment: AClasse[] clases = new AClasse[10]; just initializes the array with 10 elements, but all objects in the array are not created yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `clases[0]` is `null` and you are trying to perform some operation on it. Check the following code:

```
public class AClasse {
    String a;

    public AClasse(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AClasse[] clases = new AClasse[10];
        // clases[0].a = "?"; // the exception is in this line

        System.out.println(clases[0]);

        // Do it as follows
        clases[0] = new AClasse("?");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
null
```